# Millenium Falcon 75192 Disassembled Storage

Tags: disassembly, storage

I recently bought the Millenium Falcon 75192 and built it. I would now like to take it apart and store it. I don't have a LEGO collection, and would like to store it in a way that I won't have to dig for pieces for hours when I want to build the set again.
What would be the most compact and best organised way of storing this set disassembled?

Comment: I doubt disassembly will save much space? It looks pretty densely built to me. Can’t you just put it in a box with plenty of packing materials?

Comment: I don't have a big place that would fit the Falcon, I do have cupboards that can fit smaller boxes.

Answer (score 6):

The 75192 Millenium Falcon has [7513 Parts](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=75192-1#T=P) (as I'm sure you know) and so you're going to need to a lot of space to be able to store it.  While there are lots of great databases for LEGO parts and sets there isn't anybody who organized parts lists based on the bags in the instructions.  So you're going to be dealing with all of the parts from all of the bags during disassembly and when you get back to reassembly.  Given all of that, I would take it apart gradually and as I went I'd:

1. Sort the parts by color and shape.  It is good to have lots of plastic bins or cutlery trays to keep it sorted.
2. Bag up the minifigs.  They're mostly unique and you might as well keep them assembled in a bag instead of risking losing some of the parts.
3. Bag up the parts.  You will need ziplock or clear plastic bags in different sizes.  In some cases you will have so many of one part in one color that it is easy to just put it all in one bag.  In other cases you will have only a few and so you might put all of the different colors of one part in a bag.  Or you might put all of the bricks in one bag to save bags if there aren't many different bricks.
4. Consider printing out the part list from bricklink and verify that you aren't missing any parts.
5. Box up the bags and label the box.

I've had great luck with getting all sorts of different sized ziplock backs from Amazon or Uline.  One thing to keep in mind is that you don't need them to be air-tight or water-tight.  Using a hole-punch to make a hole in the plastic bag will allow air to go in and out and so it doesn't form a balloon in your box.

Comment: "Using a hole-punch to make a hole in the plastic bag will allow air to go in and out and so it doesn't form a balloon in your box." Or you can just leave one bit of its zip open while you squeeze the air out before sealing it.

Comment: I would think a pinhole would be safer for making sure really small parts don't disappear (like 1x1 round tiles, or light saber blades).

Answer (score 5):

The most compact way would be to disassemble the set only partially, to eliminate all empty volume but keep the parts connected, as a bunch of loose parts take up more volume as the same parts assembled. Sure, that way you will either miss out on the whole building process of will have to start by completely disassembling everything the next time.

Or if you have a LOT of time: to pick everything apart, sort the pieces, then [connect the similar pieces into solid blocks for compact storage](https://www.evilmadscientist.com/2008/how-to-organize-your-lego-bricks-for-efficient-building/):
[image]

Answer (score 4):

First of all, sort by form or size, not color. You can sort by color, but it is only suitable if you have large amount of exactly same part (no variations) and can keep them together or if they are all different in size but quite large. Otherwise, it will be a nightmare to search for that one small part in a stack of same colored elements.

Although, I have not disassembled sets with *this* much parts, but my largest Technic sets are being diassembled into 5 portions. I have never had a problem assembling them back.

Here it works for me:

1. First portion contains all smallest bits: all Technic pins and anything else shorter than 3 studs;
2. Next portion is dedicated for parts about up to 5-6 studs long (depends on set's content);
3. Then I collect something about up to 9-10 studs long;
4. Everything larger or bulk goes into here;
5. Any delicate, minifigs, larger Trans-* colored, printed or stickered elements no matter what size they are go here. Some may then be packaged individually.

I would then advise storing each portion in ziplock bags. One or another portion could be quite big and won't fit into one ziplock, so just split them. If you used size as as sorting method you won't even need to label ziplock bags as it will be easy to distinguish just by looking at the size of packaged elements.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely recommend organizing by type and not worrying about color.  For same size plates, offset stacking is a great idea.  I just finished disassembling 75192 UCS Millennium Falcon.  I picked up four tray organizers to help with the sorting.  I originally set out to back-bag the whole thing, starting with bag 17, but that approach is very difficult.  Now that I have some general organization, I plan to start bagging everything up, beginning with bag one.  This would be much easier if I had an inventory of each bag.  I wish someone smarter than me would get that website going.  I would contribute!  If I can easily generate a spreadsheet for 75192 of inventory by bag, I'll try to post it to Bricklink or somewhere.

Comment: That was my exact thought, an inventory of each bag would be helpful. I've looked around online but haven't found anything. Would you share any images of how you've ended up storing the entire set? I still have the Falcon laying around at home and want to start disassembling when I finally have some free time again!